I am using Hardhat ignition deployment and cannot obtain the actual transaction using the m.call method. I am trying to obtain its length, but it is 0
const subId = m.call(VRFCoordinatorV2Mock, "createSubscription", []);
subscriptionId = subId.logs[0].args.subId;
